# What tables are affected by "drush cc all"?

Tags: drush, caching

What database tables are affected from `drush cc all`?
Obviously, I could gather all the tables starting with cache_.

Is there any other table that is affected by this command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is dynamic, there's a convention to use `cache_` as a prefix but it's not enforced. Modules can implement [`hook_flush_caches`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_flush_caches/7.x) to register names of tables to clear:

> This hook allows your module to add cache table names to the list of cache tables that will be cleared by the Clear button on the Performance page or whenever drupal_flush_all_caches is invoked.

So basically the answer lies in the code for the modules you have installed, and you'll need to invoke that hook to get an accurate list of tables used as cache bins.